# Error in exporting table from Python API service account-- Asset does not exist or doesn't allow this operation

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api, feature-collection, google-cloud

I am trying to export a table using the Python API and am getting the following error:

> > Asset 'my_asset_Path' does not exist or doesn't allow this operation

The exact same code works in both the code editor and the Python API when I authenticate using the client library but doesn't seem to work when I authenticate with a key from the Google Cloud Platform.

I am unable to give a reproducible example because I don't want to share my service account key but the general gist is this:

```
# Attempt export from service account
import ee
service_account = 'myserviceaccount@mybucket.iam.gserviceaccount.com'
credentials = ee.ServiceAccountCredentials(service_account, 'path/to/key/my_key.json')
ee.Initialize(credentials)

my_collection = ee.FeatureCollection('projects/earthengine-legacy/assets/users/seancliffcarter/occurrence_fromPY/rbt_NAS_duplicate')


## Do some stuff to my_collection ###


export = ee.batch.Export.table.toAsset(collection = my_collection,
                    description = 'rbt_spatially_thinned',
                    assetId = 'users/seancliffcarter/occurrence_fromPY/toy_export4')
export.start()
```

This fails with the following error code (also above):

```
'error_message': "Asset 'projects/earthengine-legacy/assets/users/seancliffcarter/occurrence_fromPY' does not exist or doesn't allow this operation."
```

However, when I do the same thing with the manual authentication, it works.

Is it possible to export intermediate assets from a service account?

Comment: Is there any other solution for service account then ? It looks like there is no way to get some data apart from exporting to asset or google drive ? Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are authenticated with a service account, you cannot export assets to a personal account. You need to authenticate with your personal account.